# Multi Value Paramerter SSRS

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a multi value parameter `@products` and the main dataset has to fetch data of particular ids depending on the value provided to `@products`. 
I gave available values for @products as specific values ( a, b and c). the main query is something like

```
select version,date from table
where ( @products=a and id in('1','2','3')
or @products=b and id in ('4','5','6')
or @products=c and id in('7','8','9'))
```

This works fine when only 1 value of `@products` is selected but throws an error on selecting multiple values.

Can anyone please help me in fixing this.

Comment: Did not declare @products.The error is Query execution failed for dataset 'Common' Incorrect syntax near ','

Comment: @avinash The parameter passing to the dataset "Common" has its value as =Parameters!Product.Value only.

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing multiple values to @products you don't want to have a where clause in which you check if @products is equal to something, since there are multiple values in there. Perhaps could rewrite the query like this:

```
select version, date from table 
where ( ('a' in (@products) and id in ('1','2','3'))
     or ('b' in (@products) and id in ('4','5','6') 
     or ('c' in (@products) and id in ('7','8','9')))
```

I'm assuming the values you are passing to @products are strings/text.  I'm not sure why you have the IDs as text as I would guess they are integers, but I left them in the query as you had them before since I didn't have that info.